# Comparing field values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to run a query that finds the following document from MongoDB database

```
{field1:"foo",field2:"barfoobar"}
```

I know for equality I can use the following query:

```
.find({ $where : "this.field1 == this.field2" })
```

In C#

```
new BsonDocument("$where", new BsonJavaScript("this.field1 == this.field2"));
```

But how I can use regex in above query?
Somthing like:

```
.find({ $where : "this.field1 like this.field2" })
```

And in C# ?

Comment: What version of MongoDB server are you using?

Comment: @Stennie My MongoDB version is 3.2

Comment: you can use `$and` query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query and check if it works for you. Let me know if it helped:

```
db.col.find( { $where: function() {
   var regex = new RegExp(this.field1);
   return (regex.test(this.field2))
} }).pretty();
```

The query above turns foo into a regex (something like /foo/) and checks if field2 matches the regex you passed.

FYI: The following statement was taken from mongodb website. Take it into consideration:

> Changed in version 3.6: The $expr operator allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language. $expr is faster than $where because it does not execute JavaScript and should be preferred where possible.

Comment: Perfect answer, but, 2 questions: 1.How to prevent the query from bringing results where field1 is an empty string. 2.Is there any way to list the following document as result? {field1:"barfoobar",field2:"bardoobar"}

Comment: For your first question, change regex.test(this.field2) with this.field1 != "" && regex.test(this.field2)
For the second one you can do this:
db.col.find( { $where: function() {
   var regex = new RegExp(this.field1);
   return (regex.test(this.field2))
} },{_id:false,field1:true,field2:true}).pretty();